# Excel worksheet error

Tags: php, excel-2007

I am trying to create dynamic excel sheet, with the help of php using XML Spreadsheet.
But when I try to open the dynamically created excel sheet I keep on getting error that says 'Unable to load worksheet, problem with worksheet settings'. When I try to look at the log file it had created it shows the below text,

```
XML ERROR in Worksheet Setting
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\5XZ039FS\output[3].xls
GROUP:  Worksheet
TAG:    Table
ATTRIB: ExpandedRowCount
VALUE:  4
```

Can anybody tell what does the above error mean and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing a sample of the xml that you're trying to open in Excel or the PHP code that you used to create it, I'd guess that you specified `4` for the `ExpandedRowCount` attribute when in fact you have more than 4 rows of data.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx#odc_xmlss_ss:table):

> ss:ExpandedRowCount
>
> Specifies the total number of rows in
>   this table without regard for
>   sparseness. This attribute defines the
>   overall size of the table, if the
>   specified rows and columns were
>   expanded to full size. If specified,
>   this attribute must be in sync with
>   the table. Row indices in the table
>   should begin at 1 and go to
>   ExpandedRowCount. If this value is
>   out-of-sync with the table, the
>   specified XML Spreadsheet document is
>   invalid.

Comment: Thank you so much, this comment gave me just the lead I needed to fix my similar issue (despite assurances to the contrary Excel wasn't so good as to actually save the error logs for me!)